# grep - how to return only matched part of string on a column

Tags: html, r, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

| RandomCol | raw |
| --- | --- |
| blah | `<div style="line-height:174%;text-align:left;font-size:9pt;"><font style="font-family:inherit;font-size:9pt;font-style:italic;font-weight:bold;">We have a history of losses, and we cannot assure you that we will achieve profitability.</font></div>` |
| blahblah | `<title>WY-12blah.13-10K </title>` |

I would like to extract any font size values where they exist, using regex; I would like output that looks like this:

| RandomCol | raw | fontsize |
| --- | --- | --- |
| blah | `<div style="line-height:174%;text-align:left;font-size:9pt;"><font style="font-family:inherit;font-size:9pt;font-style:italic;font-weight:bold;">We have a history of losses, and we cannot assure you that we will achieve profitability.</font></div>` | font-size:9pt |
| blahblah | `<title>WY-12blah.13-10K </title>` |  |

The closest attempt I've made is this code:

```
df$fontsize <- ""
df$fontsize[grepl("font-size:", df$raw,ignore.case = TRUE)] <- grep("font-size:(.*?);",df$raw,ignore.case = TRUE,value=TRUE)
```

However, it gives me this:

| RandomCol | raw | fontsize |
| --- | --- | --- |
| blah | `<div style="line-height:174%;text-align:left;font-size:9pt;"><font style="font-family:inherit;font-size:9pt;font-style:italic;font-weight:bold;">We have a history of losses, and we cannot assure you that we will achieve profitability.</font></div>` | `<div style="line-height:174%;text-align:left;font-size:9pt;"><font style="font-family:inherit;font-size:9pt;font-style:italic;font-weight:bold;">We have a history of losses, and we cannot assure you that we will achieve profitability.</font></div>` |
| blahblah | `<title>WY-12blah.13-10K </title>` |  |

How do I tweak it to return only the part that matched? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `regexpr` with `regmatches`:

```
regmatches(x, regexpr("font-size:(.*?);", x, ignore.case = TRUE))
#[1] "font-size:9pt;"
```

Data:

```
x <- '<div style="line-height:174%;text-align:left;font-size:9pt;"><font style="font-family:inherit;font-size:9pt;font-style:italic;font-weight:bold;">We have a history of losses, and we cannot assure you that we will achieve profitability.</font></div>'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stringr` `str_extract` for this

```r
t <- '<div style="line-height:174%;text-align:left;font-size:9pt;"><font style="font-family:inherit;font-size:9pt;font-style:italic;font-weight:bold;">We have a history of losses, and we cannot assure you that we will achieve profitability.</font></div>'

# for the first occurence
stringr::str_extract(t, "font-size:(.*?);")
#> [1] "font-size:9pt;"


#for every occurence
stringr::str_extract_all(t, "font-size:(.*?);")
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "font-size:9pt;" "font-size:9pt;"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gsub`and backreference:

```
gsub(".*(font-size:\\d+pt).*", "\\1", t)
[1] "font-size:9pt"
```